# SimpleXML Kotlin - array of elements

Tags: kotlin, simple-framework

I've got an XML:

```
<WSDConfig>
    <files>
        <file>NewQuoteAPI.xml</file>
        <file>tratata.xml</file>
    </files>
</WSDConfig>
```

and want to parse it to List. So I have this classes:

```
@Root (name="files")
data class WSDFileDAO(@field:Element (name="file") var file : String) {
    constructor() : this("")
}

@Root (name="WSDConfig")
data class WSDConfigDAO(@field:ElementList (name="files", inline=true, required=false) var files : List<WSDFileDAO>) {
    constructor() : this(mutableListOf<WSDFileDAO>())
}

Persister().read(WSDConfigDAO::class.java, File(wsDescFileName))
```

I play with annotations and types a lot of times and now I've got an Exception:

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'file' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(name=file, type=void, data=false, required=true) on field 'file' private java.lang.String util.xml.dao.wsdesc.WSDFileDAO.file

Tell me please, what I'm doing wrong ?

**EDIT:**
And if I change class WSDFileDAO to:

```
@Root (name="files")
data class WSDFileDAO(var file : String) {
    constructor() : this("") {}
}
```

The exception is:

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'file' does not have a match in class util.xml.dao.wsdesc.WSDFileDAO

Answer (score 1):

and
so I found a solution. For XMLs of this type:

```
<WSDConfig>
    <file>NewQuoteAPI.xml</file>
    <file>tratata.xml</file>
</WSDConfig>
```

I just need to create one class like

```
@Root (name="WSDConfig")
data class WSDConfigDAO(@field:ElementList (entry="file", inline=true, required=false) var files : List<String>) {
    constructor() : this(mutableListOf<String>())
}
```

All in attribute **entry**!